# How to apply Holder's inequality to this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, holder-inequality

I want to show the following:

On a set of real numbers that has finite measure, if $a > b$ and $||f_n - f||_a \rightarrow 0$, then $||f_n - f||_b \rightarrow 0$ as well.

Perhaps I should be using Holder to say that $||f_n - f||_a \geq ||f_n - f||_b$, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: Hint: write $(f_n - f)^b$ as $(f_n - f)^b \cdot 1$ and apply Holders inequality with suitable exponents to bound this by an expression containing an integral of $(f_n - f)^a$ and an integral of the constant function $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\int |f_n-f|^{b} \leq (\int |f_n-f|^{b})^{a/b})^{b/a} (\int 1^{t} )^{1/t}$ where $t=\frac a {a-b}$. (Note that $\frac 1 t +\frac b a =1)$.